# How to italicize superscripts and subscripts in math mode?

Tags: subscripts, superscripts, italic

I'm pretty new in `LaTeX`, but I was surprised when in math mode subscripts and superscripts weren't italic. How can I solve this issue?

Here's my code:

```
$(Z(\bm{\mathrm{s}}\textsubscript{1}), ...,
Z(\bm{\mathrm{s}}\textsubscript{n}))\textsuperscript{\mathit{T}}$
```

[image: code_sub_sup]

I'm talking about the "1", the "n" and the "T" characters. Thank you all.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the name implies, the commands `\textsubscript` and `\textsuperscript` are used to typeset subscripts and superscripts in *text* mode, not in math mode. Indeed, compiling your code in the minimal document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
$(Z(\bm{\mathrm{s}}\textsubscript{1}), ..., Z(\bm{\mathrm{s}}\textsubscript{n}))\textsuperscript{\mathit{T}}$
\end{document}
```

yields the error

```
LaTeX Error: \mathit allowed only in math mode. [...tsubscript{n}))\textsuperscript{\mathit{T}}]
```

because `\mathit` is a math command, whereas `\textsuperscript` expects its argument to be text.

To typeset subscripts and superscripts in math mode, you should use `_` and `^` respectively. So your code should rather be something like the following.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
$(Z(\bm{\mathrm{s}}_1), ..., Z(\bm{\mathrm{s}}_n))^T$
\end{document}
```

Then the "n" and the "T" are italic, as usual math characters.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the banal error, I'm practicing with OverLeaf and I didn't see it.

Comment: I'm glad that it helped you! :) If it solves your problem, you can mark the answer as "accepted", as explained in the [help center](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). It helps to keep the site organized if the problem is solved.

Comment: By the way, `\bm{\mathrm{s}}` is a complicated way to get `\mathbf{s}`.

Comment: Overleaf is somewhat notorious for making errors a bit too hard to notice.  Look for the red number above the pdf.

Comment: Thank you all for the helpful advices!